# Problems communicating between C and Python programs

Tags: python, c, sockets, python-2.7, udp

I am trying to implement a UDP communication protocol between a C program and a python program. The C program has a structure that it sends through the UDP port (tx_port) as binary data. This program also listens on another port (rx_port) for any received data, and then prints the received binary output to the screen.

The python program listens on tx_port and unpacks the received  data and prints it to the screen. Then it repacks the data and sends it back through UDP port (rx_port).

Here are the C and Python programs that I used.

C program

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define BUFLEN 4096
#define RX_PORT 8888
#define TX_PORT 8889


// Structure data
struct data { 
    long frame_number;
    double time;
} tx_data, rx_data;
int dlen = sizeof(tx_data);

struct sockaddr_in si_me, si_other;
int tx_soc;
int slen = sizeof(si_other);
int recv_len;
char* buf;
pthread_t rx_thread;

void* receiver_thread(void *arg)
{
    int  i =0;
    while (1) {
        recv_len = recvfrom(tx_soc, buf, sizeof(rx_data), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen);
        printf("\nReceived data :   %d\n", recv_len);
        for (i = 0; i < recv_len; i++) {
            printf("%x ", buf[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    };
}

void data_init(void) {
    tx_data.frame_number = 0;
    tx_data.time = 0;
};

int main(void)
{
    // Initialize data
    data_init();

    //create a UDP socket
    if ((tx_soc=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
    {
        printf("Socket error!");
        exit(0);
    }

    // zero out the structure
    memset((char *) &si_me, 0, sizeof(si_other));
    memset((char *) &si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));

    // Host socket address
    si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_me.sin_port = htons(RX_PORT);
    si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    // Remote socket address
    si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_other.sin_port = htons(TX_PORT);
    si_other.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    //bind sockets to the ports
    if( bind(tx_soc, (struct sockaddr*)&si_me, sizeof(si_me) ) == -1)
    {
        printf("Binding error!");
    }

    // Start reader thread.
    if (pthread_create(&rx_thread, NULL, &receiver_thread, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("\ncan't create thread");
    }

    //keep listening for data
    while(1)
    {
        // Allocate memory for receive buffer.
        buf = (char*) malloc(sizeof(rx_data));
        // Update data value.
        tx_data.frame_number++;
        printf("\nFrame numner: %ld", tx_data.frame_number);
        fflush(stdout);
        // Send data.
        if (sendto(tx_soc, (char*)&tx_data, dlen, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &si_other, slen) == -1)
        {
            printf("Sending error!");
        }
        sleep(1);
    }

    close(tx_soc);
    return 0;
}
```

Python program

```py
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
from twisted.internet import reactor
import struct

# Packet format string
packet_fmt = ''.join(['i',          # Frame number
                      'd',          # Frame time stamp
                      ])

s = struct.Struct(packet_fmt)

class Echo(DatagramProtocol):

    def datagramReceived(self, data, (host, port)):
        new_data = s.unpack(data)
        print new_data
        echo_data = s.pack(*new_data)
        self.transport.write(echo_data, (host, port))


reactor.listenUDP(8889, Echo())
reactor.run()
```

When I execute the two programs, I am able to receive data on both sides. I am able to unpack data in python, print it, repack and send it.

But on the C side, the received data does not match the sent data. I have checked on the python side to make sure the repacked data matches the original data.

Here is a sample output from the C and Python programs. I started the python programs first, and then the C program.

[image]

What is the mistake I might be making?

Comment: on my machine both `16` bytes (C struct and Python Struct). Try to move `buf = (char*) malloc(sizeof(rx_data));` outside of the while loop in the main thread to the receiving thread.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thank you. That was the problem. I cannot believe that I put that malloc inside the loop. I have changed it and it works fine.